# Why error???Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: vb.net

Why the code is not running.

Exporting mdb file to excel file

```
   Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\jjj.mdb")
    con.Open()


    'New sheet in Workbook
    Dim AccessCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * INTO [Excel12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\User\Music\Book11.xls;HDR=NO;].[Sheet7] from [jj] ", con)

    AccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open an Excel 2003 spreadsheet with C#. Could not find installable ISAM. Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644331/open-an-excel-2003-spreadsheet-with-c-could-not-find-installable-isam-excepti)

Answer (score 0):

I ever got errror **"Could not find installable ISAM"** in VB6. But I'm not sure this error is same mine.
My solution is re-install visual studio and select all **"Data-Access"** option and it has been solved.
Please see link below for yours. And I'll add other link if I found

- [Getting “Cannot find installable ISAM” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645013/getting-cannot-find-installable-isam-error)